# Loop through OperationIDs and count if the operation has request with particular function

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, kql

I've a requirement to get the count of operations which has particular functions.

E.g.

- ***Operation 1***
- Function 1
- Function 2
- Function 3
- Function 4
- ***Operation 2***
- Function 1
- Function 2
- ***Operation 3***
- Function 1
- Function 2
- Function 3

***- Operation 4***

- Function 1
- Function 2
- Function 3
- Function 4

Here I want to write a query which will give results **Operation 1 & Operation 4**
Because they contain "Function 3 & 4" both.

Any helps? pls

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve, and what is your input exactly (e.g. is ["Function 3", "Function 4"] that you mention in your last sentence an input, or something you want to be deduced?). Please edit the question to explicitly state your input, and the expected output.

Comment: Requirement - I want to filter out all OperationIDs where it has entries of Function 3 & 4 both. Not sure if I could explain it now also not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

requests
| where name == "POST Home/Function3"
| join kind = inner
(requests
| where name == "POST Home/Function4")
on $left.operation_Id == $right.operation_Id

Comment: This answer was posted by the author of the question, while the question itself is not clear. I suggest deleting the question from stackoverflow.